# Sheriff badge description has two periods

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, badge-description

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff

The description ends with two periods. On the [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), the Sheriff badge is the only badge having a period at the end of its description.

Comment: How dare them waste space on the interN3ts lookie here --> no periods

Comment: Is this really a bug?  I think not!

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd like to know how you can disagree with correct grammar.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the concepts of badges for being a Diamond mod.

Comment: @JonH Not a bug, really. But it's not [tag:feature-request] or [tag:support]. Perhaps [tag:discussion].

Comment: @Undo - The badges are not for _being_ a diamond mod. They are for _serving_ as one for a good long while.

Comment: Its a new tag - [overlooked] or [forgotten]

Comment: @Oded still, seems like it's an incentive for high-rep users who have everything else to become a mod just for the badge - which isn't what we want.

Comment: @Undo - Note that for elected mods, they have to have been moderating for a year. And believe me, if they do **not** pull their weight, they will not last a year. Same for pro-tems.

Comment: @Undo: I don't believe there are very many high-rep users out there that would go through the trouble of serving as a moderator for a whole year *just* to seek a gold badge.

Comment: @animuson - What was it that Won't called it? Being a s**t umbrella?

Comment: @Oded That is so accurate. He was a good s**t umbrella-ella-ella too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build..